# Save in excel from visual basic studio

Tags: vba

I need to save from Visual Studio 2015 in Excel, the routine I have currently works for me but does not save the information as required, ie every time I press the save button you must add the information one underneath the other, which makes the code Is simply replacing the cell that was previously saved. Copy the code I use to save. I hope you can help me.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object

    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.add                   
    oSheet = oBook.WorkSheets(1)

     oSheet.Range("A9").Value = "Supply Ducts"

        oSheet. Range("C5:E5"). Merge(True)
        oSheet. Range("A5:B5"). Merge(True)
        oSheet.Range("A5").Value = "Project Name:"

        oSheet. Range("C6:E6"). Merge(True)
        oSheet. Range("A6:B6"). Merge(True)
        oSheet.Range("A6").Value = "Engineering Name:"

        oSheet. Range("C7:E7"). Merge(True)
        oSheet. Range("A7:B7"). Merge(True)
        oSheet.Range("A7").Value = "Company Name:"

        oSheet.Range("A10").Value = "tramo"
        oSheet.Range("B10").Value = "Caudal de Diseño     PCM"
        oSheet.Range("C10").Value = "Velocidad de Diseño     pie/min"
        oSheet.Range("D10").Value = "Factor de Fricción"
        oSheet.Range("E10").Value = "Diámetro Equivalente     in"
        oSheet.Range("F10").Value = "Alto del Ducto     in"
        oSheet.Range("G10").Value = "Ancho del Ducto     in"
        oSheet.Range("H10").Value = "Longitud del Ducto      mts"
        oSheet.Range("I10").Value = "Longitud del Ducto Equivalente     ft"
        oSheet.Range("J10").Value = "Espesor"
        oSheet.Range("K10").Value = "Calibre"
        oSheet.Range("L10").Value = "Kg Ductos"
        oSheet.Range("M10").Value = "M2 Aislante"
        oSheet.Range("N10").Value = "Delpa P    in.c.a."


            oSheet.Range("A09").End(XlDirection.xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Tramo
            oSheet.Range("B09").End(XlDirection.xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Qdiseño
            oSheet.Range("C09").End(XlDirection.xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Velocidad2
            oSheet.Range("D09").End(XlDirection.xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = FactorFriccion
            oSheet.Range("E09").End(XlDirection.xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Diameduct
            oSheet.Range("F09").End(XlDirection.xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Larcduct
            oSheet.Range("G09").End(XlDirection.xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Anchduct
            oSheet.Range("H09").End(XlDirection.xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Longducto
            oSheet.Range("I90").End(XlDirection.xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = (Longducto * 3.28084)
            oSheet.Range("J90").End(XlDirection.xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = espesor
            oSheet.Range("K09").End(XlDirection.xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = calibre
            oSheet.Range("L09").End(XlDirection.xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = (Anchduct + Larcduct) * espesor * Longducto * 11.64
            oSheet.Range("M09").End(XlDirection.xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = (Anchduct + Larcduct + 4) * Longducto * 0.1016
            oSheet.Range("N09").End(XlDirection.xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = ((Longducto * 3.28084 * FactorFriccion) / 100) * 1.05


            oExcel.Visible = True
            oExcel.UserControl = True

            oBook.SaveAs(Environ("UserProfile") & "\desktop\Ductos1.xls")

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this code is supposed to do. If the code adds "the information one underneath the other", how is it "simply replacing the cell that was previously saved"? I suspect that you'd have much better luck connecting with Excel via ADO.NET instead of using the object model.  It looks like you're using it more like a database anyway.

Comment: `oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.add` Every time you press the button you're creating a new workbook and saving it over the existing one.  You should be opening the existing workbook and just adding a line...

Comment: Perfect, thank you, I'll try it

Comment: Ready works very well, excellent thanks